# convert a dict of dict to json

Tags: java, python, json, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dict of dict to json in order to read it with java (jsonLib java).
The problem here is that I have a big Json file (130 mb) and it seems that all the date is in only one line!
so I have a java out of memory exception when I try to read the file ( I read it with BufferedReader from java.io)

here is the code for dumping the json file:

```
    import json
    instance ={}
    instance['key1']= [a,b]
    instance['key2'] = dict of dict of dict
    instance['key3'] = dict
    instance['key4'] = dict of dict of dict 
    instance['key5'] = dict of dict

    json.dump(instance,outputFile)
```

So how can I organize the json file in order to parse it as simple as possible in java.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Then it's a Java issue in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, your example is not very enlightening. Could you paste `dump` to start with? But since the actual exception occurs in the Java code, there might something afoot there too, does the exception happen inside jsonLib or in your code?

Comment: @Skurmedel: I assume it comes from `from json import dump`.

Comment: possible in java or javascript ? !

Comment: @delnan: Ok, never used that library. Still, the example is hardly telling us much. For all I know `dict1` could amount to `{}`.

Comment: I have edited my question. the dicts have many keys ( 23000 for the biggest one). The problem is how can I write the dicts in the json file without having them in the same line. I triyed the ident but when I read the file java , It takes a lot of time because there is only one value/key per line , so the file is bigger ( because of the end of line) and longer!

Answer (score 0):

You could break up the JSON payload into multiple files, perhaps one for each dict.

Comment: the problem is that the json file is written in one line , even if I brake up the json file, I would have an out memory exception. I don't know how to write the json properly in a file to read it easily in java

Comment: What I really meant is that you could break up your JSON object and serialize those objects separately. Or if you have one object holding a really large data value, you might want to think about how you can decompose that value into a data structure that is more effectively serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this http://jackson.codehaus.org/ and this http://outerthought.org/blog/415-ot.html